# What is the `#` symbol in a link with Google Analytics campaign tracking parameters?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, url-parameters, symbols

This is the link when I generate the tracking tail with [Campaign URL Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/) today:

```
http://example.com#utm_source=Campaign%20Source&utm_medium=Campaign%20Medium&utm_campaign=Campaign%20Name
```

Notice the `#` symbol after `example.com`. Why is it not `&` as usual (or as I usually see)? What is the difference between the two symbols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have checked the option *Set the campaign parameters in the fragment portion of the URL (not recommended)* immediately under the field that gives you the completed URL, then the URL builder will append the parameters with a `#` instead of a `?`.

By default GA will look for custom `utm` campaign tracking parameters appended with a `?` or `#`.

- that only applies to custom `utm` campaign tracking parameters though, anything else appended with or following after a `#` will not be tracked without modifying the GA tracking code snippet.

Not sure why it says not recommended. In days gone by, it was considered "better" practice to use a `#` for unpaid campaign `utm` parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. So both `#` and `?` are acceptable, and none of them has a special use than the other? But then, what does that option mean? And do you mean that to use the `#`, I need to modify the code snippet?

Comment: Yes, both # and ? are acceptable..  some sites due to how they are setup do not recognize parameters appended with a ? they will get removed. Using a # instead can be a quick,easy alternative.  No you dont have to edit the code snippet if you are only appending utm custom campaign parameters with the #
eg example.com/#utm_source=testsource&utm_medium=testmedium&utm_campaign=testcamp&some=param will track the source/med/campaign fine, but &some=param wont show in the pageview report as part of the url unless the tracking code is edited to work with anchors for other appended parameters

Comment: But using a `?` can dramatically slow page speed down compared to a `#`.